# C# scope differences when overriding vs hiding base-class methods

Tags: c#, scope, overriding

I am trying to learn the basics of inheritance in C#, and have realized there are gaps in my understanding of scope and accessibility. An example to illustrate:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace InheritanceTests {
    class Program {
        public static void Main() {
            (new A()).Foo();      // A: 1
            (new B()).Foo();      // B: 2
            ((A)(new B())).Foo(); // B: 2 (+)
            (new C()).Foo();      // C: 3 
            ((A)(new C())).Foo(); // A: 1 (++)
        }
    }
    class A {
        private int x = 1;
        public virtual void Foo() { MessageBox.Show("A: " + this.x); }
    }
    class B : A {
        private int x = 2;
        public override void Foo() { MessageBox.Show("B: " + this.x); }
    }
    class C : A {
        private int x = 3;
        public new void Foo() { MessageBox.Show("C: " + this.x); }
    }
}
```

I have questions about (+) and (++), that are likely related:

Regarding (+), why is the `B` instance's private field `x` accessible even after the cast to `A`?

Regarding (++), why when `A`'s `Foo` method is executed does `this.x` not evaluate to 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Regarding (+), why is the B instance's private field x accessible even after the cast to A?

Accessible to whom? In your example, `B.Foo()` is called, because `B` has overridden `A.Foo()` (which is `virtual`). Since the method being called is in fact in class `B`, the method uses the `x` field declared in `B`. That's the only field `x` that method can see.

The field `x` in `A` isn't visible to `B` anyway, since it's `private`. But if it were (i.e. if it were something other than `private`), the field `x` in `B` would hide it and the `B` implementation of `Foo()` would still use `x` from the `B` class, not from `A`.

> Regarding (++), why when A's Foo method is executed does this.x not evaluate to 3?

In this example, the derived class `C` has *not* overridden the original method `Foo()` in `A`. Instead, it's declared a whole new method `Foo()`. But by casting the object back to `A`, the compiler no longer knows about the method declared in `C`. The only method it can see is `A.Foo()`, which is *not* overridden, and so the `A` implementation of `Foo()` is called.

And of course, that implementation can see only the `x` field declared in `A`, where the method itself is declared. Hence, you get `1` in the output instead of `3`.